External Credential: Custom Headers not Working (in OAuth Client Credentials/Secret Flow )
I have an external system that exposes an API with 2 endpoints:

Token endpoint: Receives an Id + a Secret in the Authorization header, and a custom value in the user-agent header, and returns an access token.
Data endpoint: Receives that access token in a custom CLIENT-TOKEN header, plus some other parameters, and returns the data accordingly.

Making these callouts separately with both Postman and pure Apex work just fine.
Now, I'm trying to do the same thing using External Credentials + Named Credentials, so what I did was:

Created an External Credential of protocol OAuth 2.0 and flow type Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow
Added a Principal to it with both Id and Secret
Unchecked the option Pass client credentials in request body (because I want the Authorization header to be generated instead, when calling the token endpoint)
Created a custom header user-agent containing the custom value the API requires
Added the External Credential Principal Access and User External Credentials permissions to my user's profile.




I also created a Named Credential and associated it with the External Credential
Unchecked the Generate Authorization Header flag (because I only need the custom CLIENT-TOKEN header with the actual token, for the data endpoint)
Checked the Allow Formulas in HTTP Header flag (because I suspect I'll need a formula to access the token value retrieved in the token endpoint, and populate the custom CLIENT-TOKEN header, for the data endpoint)
Added the same user-agent custom header and custom value as I did in the External credential.



And finally, I did the callout using a Apex script


Now my problem is, when I run this, it fails because no token is generated. I can see the requests that are coming into the external system, and I noticed that the user-agent header is being populated with the SFDC-Callout/60.0 value, instead of being populated with the custom value I included in the Custom Headers sections of the External Credential.
So, my question is, how I can overwrite this header in order to make this work? I cannot change the external system implementation/apis to accept values other than this custom one in this header.
As an additional question, suppose I'm able to retrieve that token successfully, how can I access its value in order to populate yet another custom header in the subsequent data endpoint? Is that some sort of formula?
Thank you.

If this header was truly your own, private, special header, then not able to inject it might be a bug. Overriding a standard header and doing so in a spec-standard flow shouldn't be allowed, in our opinion. Open a support case.
